# Microservice Adapter. One for many or many / countries to one / country. Architectural/deployment decision

Tags: deployment, architecture, microservices

Say, I have System1 that connect to System 2 through the adapter-microservice between them.

```
System1 -> rest-calls --> Adapter (converts request-response + some extra logic, like validation) -> System2
```

System1 is more like **a monolith, exists for many countries** (but it may change).

Question is: From the perspective of MicroService architecture and deployment, should the Adapter be one per country. Say Adapter-Uk, Adappter-AU, etc. Or it should be just the Adapter that could handle many countries at the same time?

I mean:

To have a **single system/adapter-service** :

**Advantage**: is having one code-base in or place, **the adaptive code-logic between countries in 90 % are the same**. Easy to introduce new changes.

**Disadvantage**: once we deploy the system, and there is a bug, it could affect many countries at the same time. Not safe.

**To have a separate system**:

**Disadvantage**: once some generic change has been introduced to one system, then it should be "copy-pasted" for all other countries/services. Repetitive, not smart.. work, from developer point of view.

**Advantage**:
Safer to change/deploy.

Q: what is a preferable way from the point of view of microservice architecture?

Comment: Is your adapter domain large enough that you would plan on having separate teams taking care of the separate country services? Would the separate teams benefit from being able to develop/deploy independently? If you would not consider separate teams it may be an indication that separation by countries is not the right choice.

Comment: At a high level, w/o knowing much about the domain, you need to make sure to identify the right domain boundary, which should be the pre-requisite for having a separate microservice. Also, as a general rule of thumb, the service should be client agnostic.

Comment: @ses Were you able to figure out the best solution here? I have a similar setup and your suggestion would be quite helpfull

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

- the adapter covers all countries in order to maintain single codebase and improve code reusability
- unit and/or integration tests to cope with the bugs
- spawn multiple identical instances of the adapter with load balancer in front

Answer (score 0):

Since **Prabhat Mishra** asked in the comment.
After two years.. (took some time to understand what I have asked.)

Back then, for me was quite critical to have a resilient system, i.e. if I change a code in one adapter I did not want all my countries to go down (it is SAP enterprise system, millions clients). I wanted only once country to go down (still million clients, but fewer millions :)).

So, for this case: i would create many adapters one per country, BUT, I would use some code-generated common solution to create them, like common `jar` - so I would would not repeat my `infrastructure` or communication layers. Like scaffolding thing.

1. country-adapter new "country-1"
2. add some country specific code (not changing any generated one (less code to repeat, less to support))

Otherwise, if you feel safe (like code reviewing your change, making sure you do not change other countries code), then 1 adapter is Ok.

Another solution, is to start with 1 adapter, and split to more if it is critical (feeling not safe about the potential damage / cost if fails).

In general, seems, all boils down to the same problem, which is: WHEN to split "monolith" to pieces. The answer is always: when it causes problems to be as big as it is. But, if you know your system well, you know in advance that WHEN is now (or not).